# Group and sum array of hashes by date

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I have an array of hashes like this:

```
[{:created=>Fri, 22 Jan 2014 13:02:13 UTC +00:00, :amount=>20}, 
{:created=>Fri, 27 Jan 2014 13:14:57 UTC +00:00, :amount=>15}, 
{:created=>Fri, 27 Jan 2014 14:42:40 UTC +00:00, :amount=>10}, 
{:created=>Fri, 28 Jan 2014 15:26:58 UTC +00:00, :amount=>10}, 
{:created=>Fri, 28 Jan 2014 15:30:18 UTC +00:00, :amount=>20}, 
{:created=>Fri, 31 Jan 2014 15:32:46 UTC +00:00, :amount=>50}, 
{:created=>Fri, 31 Jan 2014 15:33:29 UTC +00:00, :amount=>40}]
```

I'd like to group those hashes by date and sum the amounts. So, in my example, the output would be:

```
[{:created=>"2014-01-22", :amount=>20}, 
{:created=>"2014-01-27", :amount=>25}, 
{:created=>"2014-01-28", :amount=>30}, 
{:created=>"2014-01-31", :amount=>90}]
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'd do as below :

```
require 'date'

a = [{:created=> 'Fri, 22 Jan 2014 13:02:13 UTC +00:00', :amount=>20}, 
{:created=>'Fri, 27 Jan 2014 13:14:57 UTC +00:00', :amount=>15}, 
{:created=>'Fri, 27 Jan 2014 14:42:40 UTC +00:00', :amount=>10}, 
{:created=>'Fri, 28 Jan 2014 15:26:58 UTC +00:00', :amount=>10}, 
{:created=>'Fri, 28 Jan 2014 15:30:18 UTC +00:00', :amount=>20}, 
{:created=>'Fri, 31 Jan 2014 15:32:46 UTC +00:00', :amount=>50}, 
{:created=>'Fri, 31 Jan 2014 15:33:29 UTC +00:00', :amount=>40}]

hsh = a.group_by { |h| Date.parse h[:created] }.map do |k,v| 
  {:created => k.to_s,:amount => v.map {|h1| h1[:amount]}.inject(:+)} 
end
hsh
# => [{:created=>"2014-01-22", :amount=>20},
#     {:created=>"2014-01-27", :amount=>25},
#     {:created=>"2014-01-28", :amount=>30},
#     {:created=>"2014-01-31", :amount=>90}]
```

Comment: I think Arup was wise to parse the strings to a date, but `...group_by { |h| h[:created].first(16) }...` also works (or you could use a regex).  One advantage of using `Date.parse` is that is will raise an exception if it finds a date string is not legit.

Comment: except that the OP's date values are not strings; they are `Date` objects (otherwise they would be quoted).

Comment: @Matt No big deal... In that case, I would use `h[:created].to_s` instead of `Date.parse h[:created]` .. And instead of `:created => k.to_s..`, I would write `:created => k..`. But what I wrote, that was the whole idea.