# Merge multiple arrays of hashes and perform calculation

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I have 2 arrays of hashes:

```
charges = [
   {:created=>"2014-01-28", :charge=>43677}, 
   {:created=>"2014-01-29", :charge=>37980}, 
   {:created=>"2014-01-30", :charge=>87354}, 
   {:created=>"2014-01-31", :charge=>43677}
]

fees = [
   {:created=>"2014-01-28", :fee=>3230}, 
   {:created=>"2014-01-29", :fee=>2380}, 
   {:created=>"2014-01-30", :fee=>2210}, 
   {:created=>"2014-01-31", :fee=>1870}
]
```

What I need to do is take the `fees` and subtract them from the `charges` for each date and output the calculated amount like so:

```
totals = [
   {:created=>"2014-01-28", :amount=>40447}, 
   {:created=>"2014-01-29", :amount=>35600}, 
   {:created=>"2014-01-30", :amount=>85144}, 
   {:created=>"2014-01-31", :amount=>41870}
]
```

Note, it's possible that there won't always be both a fee and a charge for a given day. So in the case of no fee, you just wouldn't subtract anything (or you'd subtract `0`). In the case of fees but no charges, you'd have a negative number.

Comment: Didn't you just ask a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21535854/group-and-sum-array-of-hashes-by-date)? The answer is very similar.

Comment: @ChrisHeald This is taking 2 separate arrays of hashes., finding the matching date for each, subtracting numbers, and then spitting out a new array of hashes. Previous question involved a single array of hashes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do

```
charges = [
   {:created=>"2014-01-28", :charge=>43677}, 
   {:created=>"2014-01-29", :charge=>37980}, 
   {:created=>"2014-01-30", :charge=>87354}, 
   {:created=>"2014-01-31", :charge=>43677}
]

fees = [
   {:created=>"2014-01-28", :fee=>3230}, 
   {:created=>"2014-01-29", :fee=>2380}, 
   {:created=>"2014-01-30", :fee=>2210}, 
   {:created=>"2014-01-31", :fee=>1870}
]

total = (fees + charges).group_by{ |h| h[:created] }.map do |k,v|
  val_hsh = v.each_with_object({}) do |h1,h2| 
    h1[:fee] ? h2[:fee] = h1[:fee] : h2[:charge] = h1[:charge]
  end
  {created: k, amount: val_hsh[:charge] - val_hsh[:fee]}
end

total 
# => [{:created=>"2014-01-28", :amount=>40447},
#     {:created=>"2014-01-29", :amount=>35600},
#     {:created=>"2014-01-30", :amount=>85144},
#     {:created=>"2014-01-31", :amount=>41807}]
```

**update**

```
charges = [
   {:created=>"2014-01-28", :charge=>43677}, 
   {:created=>"2014-01-29", :charge=>37980}, 
   {:created=>"2014-01-30", :charge=>87354}, 
   {:created=>"2014-01-31", :charge=>0}
]

fees = [
   {:created=>"2014-01-28", :fee=>3230}, 
   {:created=>"2014-01-29", :fee=>0}, 
   {:created=>"2014-01-30", :fee=>2210}, 
   {:created=>"2014-01-31", :fee=>1870}
]

total = (fees + charges).group_by{ |h| h[:created] }.map do |k,v|
  val_hsh = v.each_with_object({}) do |h1,h2| 
    h1[:fee] ? h2[:fee] = h1[:fee] : h2[:charge] = h1[:charge]
  end
  {created: k, amount: val_hsh[:charge] - val_hsh[:fee]}
end

total 
# => [{:created=>"2014-01-28", :amount=>40447},
#     {:created=>"2014-01-29", :amount=>37980},
#     {:created=>"2014-01-30", :amount=>85144},
#     {:created=>"2014-01-31", :amount=>-1870}]
```

Comment: Nice!  However, the charge should be subtracted from the fee, not added.

Comment: @WayneConrad sorry.. doing.. :)

Comment: Is there a way to get the output to be the subtracted value as I have in my example, instead of the array of both values?

Comment: @Shpigford Please check

Comment: @ArupRakshit Only thing I'm noticing is if, for instance, fees are blank for a given date, it makes the total amount a negative number.

Comment: I think the problem is that right now it assumes both values will be present (which is my fault, since I didn't clarify). It's possible for dates to have a charge but no fee or a fee but no charge. I added a note at the end of the post to clarify

Comment: @Shpigford Is it not working ? What is the problem, could you tell me?

Comment: @ArupRakshit Make one of the fees in the sample data `0` and you'll see.

Comment: @Shpigford It is working, as you asked in the *note*.

Comment: Ah, didn't realize you had updated your answer. Seems to be working now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to group by dates that are existent in either array, you can do as @ArupRakshit has done above: group by date then calculate.

Otherwise, I suggest you have some sort of id to identify the entries in case there are multiple entries per day -- unless you have left this out intentionally by design.

You can go with the following, assuming the arrays are sorted by id:

```
charges.zip(fees).collect { |charge, fee| { :created => charge[:created], :amount => charge[:charge] - fee[:fee] } }

=> [{:created=>"2014-01-28", :amount=>40447},
 {:created=>"2014-01-29", :amount=>35600},
 {:created=>"2014-01-30", :amount=>85144},
 {:created=>"2014-01-31", :amount=>41807}]
```